# How to install Popcorn Time using installer from their official site?

Tags: software-installation, time

How do you install Popcorntime Beta on Linux? The Beta Version is a tar.xz file that is downloaded that does not auto install when clicked on like the Windows and Mac versions do. Installing programs in Linux is Not easy for the average non advanced user if it is not a self installing file or is not available via the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: http://www.edivaldobrito.com.br/popcorn-time-no-linux/

Answer (score 43):

Updated answer: **June 2019**

1. Download [PopCorn Time for Linux](https://get.popcorntime.sh/build/Popcorn-Time-0.3.10-Linux-64.tar.xz).
2. Open a Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> ) :

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   sudo mkdir /opt/popcorntime
   sudo tar -xf Popcorn-Time-*.tar.xz -C /opt/popcorntime
   ```

   (You can now run Popcorntime with :)

   ```
   /opt/popcorntime/Popcorn-Time
   ```
3. Create the application launcher

   ```
   sudo ln -sf /opt/popcorntime/Popcorn-Time /usr/bin/Popcorn-Time
   sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/popcorntime.desktop
   ```

   And enter the following content :

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Version=1.0
   Type=Application
   Terminal=false
   Name=PopCorn Time
   Exec=/opt/popcorntime/Popcorn-Time
   Icon=/opt/popcorntime/src/app/images/icon.png
   Categories=Application;
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much! It is actually working :)
If you are using 32bit don't forget to change the code under "3. Extract the  downloaded archive" instead 64 put 32!

Although i have a small issue which is kinda bothering me. Popcorn time is now installed. But the application (icon) which i add it to the left bar doesn't work when i click it. It opens a blank window: http://postimg.org/image/qbe26i6nf/ It works only when i run the program in Download folder: http://postimg.org/image/49l2c7ffb/ How can i add this working program to left bar&change the icon/badge with original style (popcorn)? TY

Comment: No problem! I have edited my answer to take into account the 32-64 bits stuff. If my answer worked for you do not forget to click the check mark beside my answer to mark it as "valid answer" =). Sorry but I am not sure about the icon problem... I think it is related to Popcorn Time itself you should ask on their forum (don't forget it is still a beta version, some bugs left ;)

Comment: You mean "the answer is useful"? i already clicked it, but will be visible when i get at least 15 reputation:) 
Yeah I do have popcorn Time installed on 12 computers and working perfect.. Only on two computers i have problem with installing and working now, since they had some "legal issues" PPA problems.. or something like that.. not sure.. when used this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wh2j5oLFW2I everything worked perfect.. Thats why i need this icon ect.. because it is for public use:) Will keep on searching, thank you for your time and help! :)

Comment: right now the `Popcorn-Time-linux64.tar.gz` archive contains no file `install` file or anything that can really execute as is :(

Comment: As of 29/10/2016 the folder "linux64" inside the archive contains an executable "Popcorn-Time"

Comment: This answer is outdated

Comment: I have updated my answer to work with the new version of Popcorntime (2018).

Comment: I got this error while following the above steps `$ /opt/popcorntime/Popcorn-Time
/opt/popcorntime/Popcorn-Time: error while loading shared libraries: libgconf-2.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` and it went it away by `sudo apt update && sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libgconf-2-4`

Comment: i have installed in the same way. but i cannot launch the application. When i type popcorntime in terminal, it gives, `popcorntime: command not found`. Any suggestions?