# Can't Install popcorn-time

Tags: command-line

I am trying to install popcorn-time on my ubuntu computer, and I am having no success, I have looked it up but the terminal commands have not worked for me and the file does not go automatically to the install like on windows or mac what do i do?

Comment: Possible duplicate: (http://askubuntu.com/questions/675526/how-to-install-popcorn-time-using-installer-from-their-official-site)

Comment: @kek_kek Next time you flag a duplicate question, please check its answers for broken links. I have edited the first answer that had a broken link and updated it for you.

Answer (score 0):

When you unpack it, that already is the installation. It's not a source file, it's a binary precompiled proprietary blob.

These are the steps to install.

1. Download it from https://popcorntime.sh/
2. Extract it
3. Now 2 ways to run it.

   - with terminal, `cd` to extracted folder and run `./Popcorn-Time`
   - create a `Popcorn-Time.desktop` file with this text:

     ```
     [Desktop Entry]
     Name = Popcorn-Time
     Comment = Comment on the program
     Exec = /home/<user>/<Folder>/Popcorn-Time-0.3.10-Linux-64/Popcorn-Time
     Icon = /home/<user>/<Folder>/Popcorn-Time-0.3.10-Linux-64/src/app/images/icon.png
     Terminal = false
     Type = Application
     ```

     Replace `<user>` and `<folder>` with your username and the folder where PCT is.