# Trying to install popcorn time 3.2 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, macbook

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on may mac-book and would like to install popcorn time(the current version is 3.2). However all the packages of popcorn time that I have downloaded either;

1. Do not have an installation file ( so I cannot use `sudo ./install` )
2. Are not executable and simply do nothing when double clicked,
3. Give me an error "***Sorry, this did not work, no `file_to_app` results to show***" when they try open with Ubuntu software installer

**EDIT 1**; This is the procedure I first used as in a popular post here in askubuntu;

1. Download PopCorn Time.
2. Open a Terminal ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> ).
3. Enter in your download folder : `cd ~/Downloads mkdir $$`
4. Extract the downloaded archive `tar -xf Popcorn-Time-*.tar.xz -C $$`
5. Run `cd $$`
6. `sudo ./install.`

   Then when `sudo ./install` returned *no such file*, I tried going into the unzipped folder and double clicking the popcorn-time file, that's when I got:

> Sorry, this did not work, no file_to_app results to show

Comment: Please edit and post the exact steps or a link to the tutorial you've been following.

Comment: Thank you for adding the steps (most are wrong because you don't know what you're doing) but a link to the tutorial you followed would be better so we can check whether that tutorial is stupid or you misunderstood something. It could be a simple matter of adapting to your own environment but it could be something else. Either way `mkdir` doesn't work following `cd` and who in his/her right mind would a call a directory "$$" anyway?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Popcorn Time using installer from their official site?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/675526/how-to-install-popcorn-time-using-installer-from-their-official-site)

Comment: Hi @CelticWarrior I have already tried the solutions featured in the posts you are linking to...they didn't work and thats why I'm seeking help

Comment: Hey tried this:https://www.reddit.com/r/PopCornTime/comments/4s0k5g/how_do_i_install_popcorn_time_on_ubuntu_1604/

Comment: What you posted doesn't make sense as I already mentioned. If you knew what the commands do you would know it. `cd ~/Downloads` is one command, `mkdir`...  is another; the former makes sense if and only if you have a folder named "Downloads" (the default downloads folder goes by different names depending on the OS main language. Then, assuming "$$" makes sense a folder's name (it doesn't) it has to be created and it wasn't because (read above). Finally, the error you got it's telling exactly that: You tried to run a file that doesn't exist. (cont.)

Comment: @Francispart2 If it works for you let me know so that I can put it as an answer if someone else doesn't beat me to it. I tried installing ptime a while back but gave up because it never worked. I just found about the reddit link today but haven't really tried it.

Comment: Now, assuming it works (I don't know, I don't care and I don't condone PIRACY), most of the steps can be done without terminal: Simply download the file (.tar.xz) anywhere you want, right-click it and "extract here...). Then and only then you need the terminal and the first thing is `cd` to the full path to the folder you extracted.  Then run it.

Comment: Thanks @Tatakai I managed to open the application. However it doesnt get to the movies it just displays "The remote Movies API failed to respond, please check http://status.... and try again later" when I follow that link it says that popcorn time is NOT experiencing any issues....Has anyone else seen this error?

Answer (score 1):

Try this bro, it's working 100 %.

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-popcorn-time-movie-player-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-linux

Answer (score 0):

There is .deb instal pac on the Internet that works on my UbuntuMate 16.04 LTS 64bit.

[image]

But my problem is that it never came further than loading / initializing; the first screen.

[image]

Has anyone experienced with that?